# Is this a thunk?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I was googling about Redux thunk and I kind of get the gist of what it's used for and how to make one and as I was about to start making it, I just realized that I may have already made one. I say **may** because I based my code from boilerplate code made by visual studio when I created a react app using asp.net core as a backend. The code in question:

```
editLecture: (lecture) => (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: EDITING_LECTURE, payload: lecture })
        const url = `api/lecture/${lecture.topicID}`
        const response = fetch(url, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(lecture)
        }).then(res =>
            res.json()
        ).then(json =>
            dispatch({ type: EDITED_LECTURE, payload: json })
        )
    }
```

So yeah, is this a thunk? PS: I'm a JS/React/Redux noob so if this comes out as an obvious answer I'm sorry..

Comment: yes this is a thunk but you mix `Promise` and `async await`, actually you don't need `async await` keyword as your are using `then` function, `const response` is useless here

Comment: The Visual Studio .NET Core React + Redux project template is using `redux-thunk` by default. The default action creators generated in that project, at least the async ones, are in fact thunks. If you look at file `configureStore.js`, you can see the redux middlewares such as redux-thunk are in action. Yours looks like a thunk.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé yeah I haven't fixed the code. It's a little cluttered because I just found out why I needed thunks and opted to use the `then` function. I'll fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yeah I saw the include statements but I wasn't sure because most of the syntax you'd find on the internet on creating thunks don't use the arrow functions. I just wanted to make sure because I needed a thunk for what I'm about to do based on what I was searching. thanks! so... what do I do with this question? can it be closed or something?

Comment: A lot of examples do in fact return nested functions rather than arrow functions, it can be made shorter with arrow functions, but has the same effect. Use whichever makes more sense to you. Regarding the question itself, I'd leave it open for now, someone may provide an answer to help understand this actionCreator as thunk in detail.